# Math fonts not rendering in Chrome (macos)

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

Some math fonts are not rendering on my chrome browser (v.108) on macos 13.2, as shown in these screenshots (where they appear as squares). I suspect it somehow related to MathML or Mathjax, but I don't know much about fonts. Is there a way for me to fix it? (These fonts render fine in Safari.)

Examples:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3252220/upper-semi-continuity-of-the-rank-of-the-fibre-of-a-sheaf renders

[image]

and https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.07499 renders

[image]

Comment: Can only confirm to (suddenly) have the same problem. Other browsers seem to not having this problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue, but following the advice [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384924/i-think-there-is-a-mathjax-bug-for-mathcal-typesetting-on-some-platforms) it was fixed.

In case that goes down here is the comment from user [postylem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/270404/postylem):

> This is a problem caused by MathJax not accessing/not having access to the required glyph in the right font. This is a bug I think (as it also arose for me when I updated to macOS Ventura) but it can be circumvented by right-clicking on the math, and selecting Math Settings > Math Renderer > Common HTML (instead of HTML-CSS).

Comment: Had the same issue on the Brave Browser for so long. This fixed it!